# Using Bigquery remove the nested columns which has "REPEATED" mode

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using Bigquery I was trying to remove nested schema like below, but couldn't able to do so. Can anyone please let me know. How to achieve that?

**Table:**

```
FiledName          Type       Mode
Person            RECORD   REPEATED
Person.Name       STRING   NULLABLE
Person.Add        RECORD   NULLABLE
Person.Add.line   STRING   NULLABLE
```

**Code:**

```
create table `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` as 
select * replace(
   (select as ARRAY(struct person.* except(add))) as person
)
from `project_id.dataset.table_name`;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
FiledName          Type       Mode
Person            RECORD   REPEATED
Person.Name       STRING   NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create table `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` as 
select * replace(
    array(select as struct person.* except(add) from t.person) as person
  )
from `project_id.dataset.table_name` t;
```

Comment: Is this replace function from String functions? This -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#replace

Comment: Nope. Check out [Modifiers for * operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#modifiers_for_operator)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
create table `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` as 
SELECT 
      [STRUCT (P.NAME AS NAME)] AS PERSON

from `project_id.dataset.table_name`,UNNEST(PERSON) AS P;
```